# ModelMapper attribute fields with correlation names, in camel case

Tags: java, mapper, modelmapper

**Error converting entity with source attribute name content in source fiels with camel case part**

Example: in source model i heve a String field **edgeId**, and in target model i heve a field Long **id**, the match is true. This generate a  exception, **java.lang.NumberFormatException**, how to ignore this match.

This is occurre with another attribute names

```
package br.com.combinado;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

public class TestModelMapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Target target = new Target();
        target.setTesteBatataFrita("batataFrinta");

        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        Source source = mapper.map(target, Source.class);
        System.out.println(source);
    }

    private static class Source {

        private Long frita;

        public Long getFrita() {
            return frita;
        }

        public void setFrita(Long frita) {
            this.frita = frita;
        }

    }

    private static class Target {
        private String testeBatataFrita;

        public String getTesteBatataFrita() {
            return testeBatataFrita;
        }

        public void setTesteBatataFrita(String testeBatataFrita) {
            this.testeBatataFrita = testeBatataFrita;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding a add a SourceNameTokenizer

```
mapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNameTokenizer(new NameTokenizer() {
    public String[] tokenize(String name, NameableType nameableType) {
        return new String[] { name };
    }
});
```

Or

```
@Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration().setDestinationNameTokenizer((name, nameableType) -> new String[] { name });
        mapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNameTokenizer((name, nameableType) -> new String[] { name });
        return mapper;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in latest versions I found a way to solve it with

```
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```